# Fill web form without submit button from vba

Tags: excel, forms, vba, internet-explorer, dom

I want to fill a form and get the response value of the form. The form I need can be found at [www.1ratio.nl](http://www.1ratio.nl)

Now this form has no submit button. I have a code in my vba that should work when there's a submit button available, but now I just won't get a response from the website.

**Edit:** Besides, is there an option to not create open a new IE screen where there's already a screen available? So that it in the last case creates a new tab instead?

**Edit 2:** I guess it may be possible to add a submit button to the website with VBA. Is this possible and is this the solution that I want?

Code:

```
Sub fillform()

zero = 1
one = 2
two = 3
three = 4
four = 1

Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "http://www.1ratio.nl"

Application.StatusBar = "Submitting"

While IE.busy
    DoEvents
Wend

delay 1
IE.document.getelementbyid("ContentPlaceHolder1_Leeftijd01DropDownList").Value = zero
delay 1
IE.document.getelementbyid("ContentPlaceHolder1_Leeftijd12DropDownList").Value = one
delay 1
IE.document.getelementbyid("ContentPlaceHolder1_Leeftijd23DropDownList").Value = two
delay 1
IE.document.getelementbyid("ContentPlaceHolder1_Leeftijd34DropDownList").Value = three
delay 1
IE.document.getelementbyid("ContentPlaceHolder1_Leeftijd48DropDownList").Value = four
delay 1
MsgBox (IE.document.getelementbyid("ContentPlaceHolder1_AantalLabel"))

End Sub

Private Sub delay(seconds As Double)
Dim endtime As Date
endtime = DateAdd("s", seconds, Now())
Do While Now() < endtime
    DoEvents
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can solve this by triggering the onchange event on the selectboxes of the HTML code with the following code:

```
IE.document.getelementbyid("ContentPlaceHolder1_Leeftijd01DropDownList").fireevent ("onchange")
```